# Access-Control-Allow-Origin header setup in Maven build web.xml

Tags: java, jquery, rest, maven, cors

When I access the REST using jQuery I am getting the below error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8185/Profile-iris/Profile.svc/GB0010001/enqEnqUserProfiles()?alt=json.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

I understand that I need to setup the Access-Control-Allow-Origin at server.

Below is the server side 'web.xml'

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>allowedOrigins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>allowedMethods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,HEAD</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>allowedHeaders</param-name>
        <param-value>origin,content-type,accept,authorization,maxdataserviceversion</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
....
....
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Jboss Log looks ok.

```
16:21:37,872 INFO  [STDOUT] 11:51:37.872 [HDScanner] DEBUG
o.e.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter - Cross-origin filter 
configuration: allowedOrigins = *, 
allowedMethods = GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,HEAD, 
allowedHeaders = origin,content-type,accept,authorization, maxdataserviceversion, 
preflightMaxAge = 1800, 
allowCredentials = true,
exposedHeaders = ,
chainPreflight = true
```

jQuery Client

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:8185/Profile-iris/Profile.svc/GB0010001/enqEnqUserProfiles()?alt=json",
                type: "GET",
                dataType : "json",

                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
```

According to my understanding the above setup looks correct.  But however I am getting the same error.  Can someone help me please.

Answer (score 1):

It happens sometimes when you are working on local environement. If it is so then you can just you Google Chrome extension :https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

install it Turn on and forget about this error message on local environments.

Comment: Thanks. I installed and enabled, but now I am getting `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8185/Profile-iris/Profile.svc/GB0010001/enqEnqUserProfiles()?alt=json. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401` Any suggestions??

Comment: HTTP 401 -> UNAUTHORIZED request I don't think this 2 issues are the same. 401 is probably different problem.